# How to fix error in error 'InvalidArgument=Value of '7' is not valid for 'index'

Tags: c#

I'm setting the listview to a format of backcolor if ever the loop finds the string it will trigger the event.

I've already trapped the function to the if else statement but the error still there.

```
foreach (ListViewItem li in listView1.Items)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Columns.Count; i++)
            {

                if (li.SubItems[i].Text.ToString() == "Pending")
                {
                    li.BackColor = Color.Turquoise;
                    li.ForeColor = Color.White;
                }
                else if (li.SubItems[i].Text.ToString() == "Paid")
                {
                    li.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    li.ForeColor = Color.White;
                }
                else if (li.SubItems[i].Text.ToString() == "Over Due")
                {
                    li.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    li.ForeColor = Color.White;
                }

            }

        }
```

This is the error I've got. 'InvalidArgument=Value of '7' is not valid for 'index'

Comment: Have you tried with `foreach (var subItems in li.SubItems)` instead of `for loop`. If yes, then is it working? If No then try with `foreach`.

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: thanks for this, it solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in your inner for loop, you are iterating over `listView1.Columns` instead of `itemRow.SubItems`

you should update your for loop, like

```
foreach (ListViewItem li in listView1.Items)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.SubItems.Count; i++)
        {                           //^^^^^^^^ this is what you need to change
            //Your code goes here
        }
    }
```

Or you can use foreach loop,

```
foreach (ListViewItem li in listView1.Items)
    {
        foreach (var subItem in li.SubItems)
        {                           
            if (subItem.Text.ToString() == "Pending") {
                  li.BackColor = Color.Turquoise;
              }
            else if (subItem.Text.ToString() == "Paid") {
                  li.BackColor = Color.Green;
              }
            else if (subItem.Text.ToString() == "Over Due") {
                  li.BackColor = Color.Red;
              }
        }
    li.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
```

> Your code is giving error might be because of
>   **`listView1.Columns.Count` is greater `listView1.SubItems.Count`**

**Bonus :** `li.ForeColor = Color.White;` is **same in all** `if..else` conditions, *you can write it outside of if..else ladder instead of writing it in each condition*. Kindly check my updated code

Comment: thank man, it solves my problem. Mark your solution as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the inner `for` loop is looping through the columns with the index of `i`. Then inside the loop there is the statement…

```
if (li.SubItems[i].Text.ToString() == "Pending")
```

This assumes that the number `ListView` “SubItems” is the same number of “Columns”. It certainly is possible for these two values to be different, hence the error.

Another approach would be to simply loop through the "subitems" themselves with another `foreach` loop like below…

```
foreach (ListViewItem li in listView1.Items) {
  foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subItem in li.SubItems) {
    if (subItem.Text.ToString() == "Pending") {
      li.BackColor = Color.Turquoise;
      li.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
    else if (subItem.Text.ToString() == "Paid") {
      li.BackColor = Color.Green;
      li.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
    else if (subItem.Text.ToString() == "Over Due") {
      li.BackColor = Color.Red;
      li.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, sir, I've marked the first answer. but you explain it great. This is more appreciated.